# Anyone know of some good Word Sense Disambiguation software?

Tags: nlp, disambiguation, word-sense-disambiguation

What represents the state-of-the-art in Word Sense Disambiguation (WSD) software? What metrics determine the state-of-the-art, and what toolkits / open source packages are available?

Comment: i've tried that already, just want to know other softwares that are available in the net.

Comment: Define "good" :-) If a toolkit approach is acceptable, then the NLTK toolkit for Python is worth looking at. Open source and there are a couple of good books, including one from O'Reilly which has been open published online. Intended for teaching, so typically each supported operation has multiple implemented algorithms, and the books have a very practical feel to them.

Comment: State-of-the-art WSD has always been changing every SemEval cycle (i.e. every 3 years). That is because the evaluation criteria has been changing due to the availability of new machine learning technology and sense-annoation/related resources.

For a thorough overview of the evaluation and WSD science developed over the years, i would recommend the SemEval wikipedia page or the SemEval portal http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=SemEval_Portal

Answer (score 12):

My list are not exhaustive but surely Googling for more will be better for your purposes.

For softwares here's a short list, remember to **CITE** the relevant sources!!!

**GWSD: Unsupervised Graph-based Word Sense Disambiguation**
http://lit.csci.unt.edu/~rada/downloads/GWSD/GWSD.1.0.tar.gz

**SenseLearner: All-Words Word Sense Disambiguation Tool**
http://lit.csci.unt.edu/~rada/downloads/senselearner/SenseLearner2.0.tar.gz

**KYOTO UKB graph-based WSD**
http://ixa2.si.ehu.es/ukb/

**pyWSD: Python Implementation of Simple WSD algorithms** https://github.com/alvations/pywsd

---

WSD tasks are sort of also dependent of the data source so here's a few, remember to **CITE** them too!!!

**Open Mind Word Expert Sense Tagged Data**
http://teach-computers.org/word-expert.html

**TWA Sense Tagged Data**
http://lit.csci.unt.edu/~rada/downloads/TWA/TWA.tar.gz

**SemCor**
http://lit.csci.unt.edu/~rada/downloads/semcor/semcor1.6.tar.gz

---

Lastly, WSD tasks are dependent on some preprocessing and if you're looking into state-of-the-art crosslingual WSD, then you should try to look out for word level aligners like

- MOSES
- MGIZA++
- GIZA++
- BerkeleyAligner

Also, look at previous Senseval/SemEval pages to look for what has already been done, and what are the trends that future tasks are moving towards. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SemEval

Comment: Hi , i need to use wordnet based WSD alongside java . Can u suggest a jar file or any package that performs this function

Comment: @2er0 Any success with your project?

Comment: Crosslingual WSD was indeed a hard task, i ranked last on the game @ SemEval-2013, but my cosine system was super 'resource-lean` and i think given enough data, it should scale properly to reach close to at least the 3rd/4th place.