# Semantic Similarity using Wu-Palmer

Tags: semantics, similarity, ambiguity

I've recently used Wu-Palmer in a project to calculate the similarity between 2 words. But there is something I'm curious about .. `Does Wu-Palmer also calculates the ambiguity or just the similarity?`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21377351/610569  and https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/pywsd/similarity.py#L19

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask