# Word-sense disambiguation based on sets of words using pre-trained embeddings

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, nltk, spacy

I am interested in identifying the WordNet synset IDs for each word in a set of tags.
The words in the set provide the context for the word sense disambiguation, such as:

- {mole, skin}
- {mole, grass, fur}
- {mole, chemistry}
- {bank, river, river bank}
- {bank, money, building}

I know of the lesk algorithm and libraries, such as [pywsd](https://github.com/alvations/pywsd), which is based on 10+ year old tech (which may still be cutting edge -- that is my question).

**Are there better performing algorithms by now that make sense of pre-trained embeddings, like [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/), and maybe the distances of these embeddings to each other?**
Are there ready-to-use implementations of such WSD algorithms?

I know this question is close to the danger zone of asking for subjective preferences - as in this 5-year old [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613773/anyone-know-of-some-good-word-sense-disambiguation-software). But I am not asking for an overview of options or the best software for a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transfer learning, particularly models like Allen AI’s ELMO, OpenAI’s Open-GPT, and Google’s BERT allowed researchers to smash multiple benchmarks with minimal task-specific fine-tuning and provided the rest of the NLP community with pretrained models that could easily (with less data and less compute time) be fine-tuned and implemented to produce state of the art results.

these representations will help you accuratley retrieve results matching the customer's intent and contextual meaning(), even if there's no keyword or phrase overlap.

To start off, embeddings are simply (moderately) low dimensional representations of a point in a higher dimensional vector space.

By translating a word to an embedding it becomes possible to model the semantic importance of a word in a numeric form and thus perform mathematical operations on it.

When this was first possible by the word2vec model it was an amazing breakthrough. From there, many more advanced models surfaced which not only captured a static semantic meaning but also a contextualized meaning. For instance, consider the two sentences below:

```
I like apples.

I like Apple macbooks
```

Note that the word apple has a different semantic meaning in each sentence. Now with a contextualized language model, the embedding of the word apple would have a different vector representation which makes it even more powerful for NLP tasks.

contextual embedding's like BERT offers an advantage over models like Word2Vec, because while each word has a fixed representation under Word2Vec regardless of the context within which the word appears, BERT produces word representations that are dynamically informed by the words around them.

Comment: That is very interesting.
Is there a word-sense disambiguation system that readily makes use of BERT (or other contextual embedding system) word representations?

Comment: you are so welcome. yes ,you can refer to this: https://medium.com/@s.aakash3431/glossbert-bert-for-word-sense-disambiguation-with-gloss-knowledge-b73412204579